# Cannot able to display data from database in Django 1.10?

Tags: html, django, postgresql

I am new to django and i cannot able to display data from postgres database, i have following data in my database,

**Data in products Table**

1 "test" "images.jpg" 1

3 "sample" "images.jpg" 2

and my code  is ,

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from products.forms import productsform
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from products.models import products
def productsview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = productsform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            image = request.POST.get('image')
            code = request.POST.get('code')
            products_obj = products(name=name,image=image,code=code)
            products_obj.save()
            return HttpResponse("Register Successfull")
    else:
        form = productsform()
    return render(request,'products/products_view.html',{'form':form,})

def display(request):
    query_results = products.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'products/myview.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.productsview, name='products'),
    url(r'^display', views.display, name='display'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pictures')
    code = models.IntegerField()
```

**myview.html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in query_results %}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.code }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sending the data to the view from the `display` function.

```
return render(request, 'products/myview.html', {'query_results': query_results})
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot passing the model to the template. In you `views.py` file, do the following:

```
def display(request):
    query_results = products.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'products/myview.html', {'query_results': query_results})
```